# Do I need to add the ground wires to plastic retro fitting lights?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, light-fixture

[image: light fixture2][light fixture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9ezL.jpg)so I am adding recessed lighting in the kitchen (about 6). these retro fit lights do not go in a metal casing. It actually has its own casing. either way its all plastic except with a few metal parts like screws and whatever is holding the screw.

I am using 14-2 wire which is black,white,ground. these lights I am installing will not touch anything metal in the ceiling, so it will be its own bare metal part.

is it still important to attach the ground wire to the LED lights metal case looking thing. or should I just entangle the ground wires together and call it a day

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Good description, but a picture or two could really help.

Comment: Do they run on mains AC, or DC power?

Answer (score 1):

I have some panel lights similar to these. The fixture cases are plastic and don't need to be grounded since you couldn't anyway.

Additionally, they are powered by low voltage DC so again don't need to be grounded.

The power supplies for the ones I have only have two wires feeding them, a hot wire and a neutral. No ground, since they are also all plastic.

Comment: thank you!! I will go ahead and twist the ground wires together then

Comment: To connect the ground wires, use a wire-nut or other approved connector.